# Get value from a html without using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#

Please check the code bellow. I want to get value of `CDN$&nbsp;23.99` from following string. Please don't advice me to use htmlagilitypack because some other reason i cant use it here. I need to match the pattern of first part like `<mama id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString">` and get value after this text pattern until its find next pattern which is- `</mama>`

How can i do this?

```
string foo = "<mama id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString">CDN$&nbsp;23.99</mama>";


string doo = "CDN$&nbsp;23.99"; //output need like this
```

Comment: Surely you don't have only string foo value as shown here but a lot of arbitrary html before and after that, right?

Comment: @Filburt yes lots of others html too but this line is unique

Comment: I just need match that first part text pattern and take value until </mama>

Comment: There are some answers to [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/205233) and related questions that may have what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a Regex

```
string foo = "<mama id=\"priceblock_ourprice\" class=\"a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString\">CDN$&nbsp;23.99</mama>";

Regex rx = new Regex(@"<mama .*>(.*)<\/mama>",
RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(foo);

string doo = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

here you have a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/TBIUBA

edit: You need to access `Groups[1]` because under `Group[0]` the value that is stored is `>(.*)<\/mama>` so the parentesis `()` create groups inside the regular expressions.

If you need more "checking" for the expression at the begginging of it. Just addit on the `Regex`instantiation `>`

Comment: You will need to make that a non-greedy match: "(.*?)" - try to add extra html at the start of foo

Comment: @HansKeﬆing you're right, I was assuming that was all the possible `HTML`, just updated to check the `mama` tag